# Notification is being disappeared from statusbar in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, nsnotificationcenter

I have implemented notification in my app. When notification gets fired, alert is disappeared without pressing Ok or cancel button from alert view of notification and it also being disappeared from status bar. This is happening while application firing notification is either in background or in foreground. what would be the reason behind it?

I want to show notification alert till user is pressed OK or Cancel button, how could I achieve it?

Do I need to have some setting in notification setting or right some code for that?

My Code is as given below..

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter3 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter3 setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy / HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *toDate = [dateFormatter3 dateFromString:timeBut.titleLabel.text];

[dateFormatter3 release];

NSLog(@"toDate=%@",toDate);

UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init]; //Create the localNotification object

[localNotification setFireDate:toDate]; //Set the date when the alert will be launched using the date adding the time the user selected on the timer

[localNotification setAlertAction:@"Launch"]; //The button's text that launches the application and is shown in the alert

 [localNotification setAlertBody:[remTextField text]]; //Set the message in the notification from the textField's text

 [localNotification setHasAction: YES]; //Set that pushing the button will launch the

 [localNotification setSoundName:UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName];

 //[localNotification setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];

 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification]; //Schedule the notification with the system

 [localNotification release];

 successalert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"DemoTable" message:@"Simple Reminder is successfully added" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];

 [successalert show];

  [successalert release];
```

I have implemented below method in appdelegate.

```
//Getting notification while running
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif  
 {   
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"DemoTable"  message:notif.alertBody delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    // delete the notification from the system
    [application cancelLocalNotification:notif] ;
  }
```

Thanks..

Comment: Are you getting notification properly when your app is in background as you set before?

Comment: @Anil: Thanks for your reply, yeah I'm getting notification properly while app is in background and forground also.

Comment: Then immediately disappearing before opening app right? Notification is like alert or is on notification bar?

Comment: after few minutes it is being disappeared. recently notification is appearing in notification bar. and I have not changed alert style from the notification center. by default it is banner.

Answer (score 0):

The default notification style in iOS6 is show the notification on the bar. In this case ***an alert will show for a few seconds and disappear, notification remains in the notification bar until user open it. This is the default behavior of the notification center. You cannot change that***. The user of your app has to decide the style of the alert wether he needs old style alert notification or notification on the notification center. If he choose old style alert from the settings of the iPhone, then only you can prompt the user to open the app through the alert button action. Otherwise app will open when the user selects the notification from the notification bar. ***This is user preference you cannot do anything with that***